# How to match text inside an array to a string and return it's value if true?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to understand how I can match an array against a line of text, if the text inside the array is found, then I'd like to return that value.

I've tried the following but nothing seems to get returned.

```
$catArray = array(
    '0' => 'breakfast',
    '1' => 'lunch',
    '2' => 'dinner',
);

$text = 'It is your breakfast';

foreach($catArray as $cat){
    if(strpos($cat, $text) !== false){
        return $cat;
    }
}
```

By this logic, `breakfast` should return.

Comment: You have the args to strpos the wrong way round

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php, signature for strpos is `mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`. Try `strpos($text, $cat)` instead.

Comment: Lol.. I've honestly been up for over 27 hours, eyes are blurry and I feel like an idiot for missing something like this.. thanks @Clive and Nima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$catArray = array(
    '0' => 'breakfast',
    '1' => 'lunch',
    '2' => 'dinner',
);
$text = 'It is your breakfast';

foreach($catArray as $cat){
    if(strpos($text, $cat) !== false){
        echo $cat;
    }
}
```

returns 
`breakfast`

so basically turn around the [haystack and the needle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in a wrong way, also you are returning the variable instead of printing.
here is the correct syntax:

```
strpos(<srting>,<find>,<start-optional>)
```

i modified your code, now it is working.

```
$catArray = array(
    '0' => 'breakfast',
    '1' => 'lunch',
    '2' => 'dinner',
);

$text = 'It is your breakfast';

foreach($catArray as $cat){
    if(strpos($text, $cat) !== false){
        echo($cat);
    }
}
```